# Vuejs toggle between marking tasks wont work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I am using Vue and I am trying to create a toggle between marked read or not read for tasks. The toggle does not want to work and I can't understand why. When I click on it absolutely nothing happens, no errors, nothing. I would appreciate it if someone can have a look

Here is my code:

```
     let bus = new Vue();

     let Task = {
        props: ['task'],
      template: `
     <div class="tasks" :class="{ 'task--done' : task.done , 'task-notdone' 
     : task.done === false }">


        {{ task.body }}
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleDone(task.id)">Mark me as {{ 
      task.done ? 'not done' : 'done' }}</a>

      </div>
      `,

      methods: {
        toggleDone(taskId) {
          bus.$emit('task: toggleDone', taskId);
       }
     }

     };

     let Tasks = {
       components:{
         'task': Task
        },

        data() {
          return {
            tasks: [
              {id: 1, body: 'Task One', done: false },
              {id: 2, body: 'Task Two', done: true },
              {id: 3, body: 'Task Three', done: true }
            ],
          }
        },

      template: `
        <div>
        <template v-if="tasks.length">
        <task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" :task="task"></task>
        </template>
        <span v-else>No tasks</span>
            <form action="">
             form
           </form>
      </div>
         `,

        methods: {
          toggleDone(taskId){
             let task = this.tasks.find(function (task) {
               return task.id === taskId;
            });

            console.log(task);
          }
        },

        mounted () {
            bus.$on('task:toggleDone', (taskId) => {
             this.toggleDone(taskId);
           })
         },
     };

       let app = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        components: {
          'tasks': Tasks,

         },


      });
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: I am not sure what exactly I should look out for in the link?

Comment: You should read the whole page (and I'd recommend reading the rest of the documentation when you have time). You need to emit an event from the child `$emit('foo', bar)` and listen to it from the parent template like `<child @foo="someMethod"/>`. You aren't doing that correctly in your code.

Comment: Maybe because you're emitting `'task: toggleDone'` but you're listening for `'task:toggleDone'`?

Comment: I would highly recommend checking out single file components as well.  That would give you intellisense if you have a good editor and would make it a little easier to find mistakes.  Also, check out the chrome extension for vue.  It can help you see what is changing behind the scenes